# Spring-free Hibernate DAO and @Repository for Exception translation! Isn't that dependency?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependencies, dao

I've read that the new way of creating Hibernate DAO is using Hibernate contextual sessions. The main reason being to avoid the Spring based `HibernateTemplate/HiberateDaoSupport` and thus Spring-Free DAO.

When I searched what to do with Exception translation? It's written everywhere that I should use `@Repository`! `@Repository` does need import and creates dependencies in my code. Am I right?

Aren't annotations considered dependency? If they are, is there anyway I can have that using XML? Or should I use the old `HibernateDaoSupport` way, since I'm going to have my code coupled with Spring anyway?

#### Update

Found a similar question: "[integrate hibernate with spring without spring dependency in dao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243459/integrate-hibernate-with-spring-without-spring-dependency-in-dao/12244626#12244626)" but:

- The first paragraph of the answer that @pap has given does not specify any clear XML alternative for @Repository.
- The insight offered in the rest of that answer is plausible, **yet my question remains unanswered** that if decoupling is not much of a concern, why did Spring try proposing the new approach to Hibernate DAO?

P.S. This is not a criticism. It's rather an attempt to learn the proper way of thinking about this topic (i.e. the dependency).

Comment: Why would you avoid Spring?

Comment: White The reason usually given is to avoid the unnecessary coupling between the DAO and Spring. If this dependency is avoidable, I say, why not?!

The problem is if/when I have to use @repository annotation, then the dependency is practically there.

Comment: @Hossuen: you are right, that annotation forces the dependency (as far as I can tell). However, the coupling between the DAO and Spring should not be avoided without good cause. Your 'why not' reason is easily answered with 'spring provides many utilities and good practices that will make the code more robust, cleaner, safer, and easier to maintain'.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I'm not talking about avoiding the _Spring_ itself, but avoiding the _dependency_ to it. That's the reason Spring is recommending the new approach. But @Repository is still needed for Exception translation, which brings us to the question above.

Comment: Also, I would say that Hibernate contextual sessions are *a* new approach and not *the* new approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Spring exception translation in the first place is to break a dependency on Hibernate by creating a dependency on Spring.  Regardless of the annotation, Spring exception translation catches a Hibernate exception and turns it into a Spring exception.  By putting catch statements in your code tied to the Spring exception you are coupling your code to Spring far more directly than by adding any @Repository annotations.  If you don't want to depend on Spring then simply use the Hibernate exceptions directly.  Basically, there are two approaches:

1. Use Hibernate for exceptions and contextual sessions (no coupling to Spring).  In this case, simply don't use Spring exception translation at all.
2. Use Spring for exceptions and session handling (looser coupling to Hibernate, additional coupling to Spring).